# timer for a social app

Tags: android, multithreading, timer

I am writing a social game but am stuck with how to create a timer thread that works accross activities showing time lapse for an attribute such as energy. Every activity has the energy textview but the thread can update only one view at a time. Please note that im not using androids timer class but have created my own thread class.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to try to keep a thread running between activities. Managing it when the activity suspends will give you nothing but headaches. It's much easier to just store your time in the [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) while you move from activity to activity. The Application is alive for the duration, no matter which Activity is actually loaded.  The fact that you have an identically named TextView in various activities is neither here nor there... it's not the "same" TextView... it just looks (and smells) similar. So, you can just grab the clock when the app first launches and at any given time look at the difference between the current time and that time.

Then just use a [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) to update the string in whatever Activity you're in.

If you're unfamiliar with Application it's going to be a real Eureka thing for you to discover (Android tutorials overlook it ALL the time, for some reason, leaving you to do all sorts of really ugly Intent passing alternatives).

If you have any questions on how to use it, just follow up in a comment, and I'll add details.

Comment: The timer scenario is not just about using the current time. Let me explain in a bit detail: The energy parameter of the player is like 12/12. so whenever the energy decreases even one point below 12, a 4mins timer starts running which updates the textview, such as energyTimerTextView, which is placed on the header of every activity. I've already using fragment for the header where this text view is placed. And managed to make it work with a universal timer thread which places the time lapsed in sharedpreferrences from where any textview can read and display. but i think its a big big overkill

Comment: Reading SharedPreferences is fairly good miles per gallon, but I still don't see why you don't simply put a variable in the Application that stores whatever time is your "start" time and then just compare against that whenever your needs call for it.  You reset it, just as easily, if that's what you need to have happen. I must not be understanding your needs correctly cause it seems like the obvious thing to do, to me.

Comment: Dr.Dredel is actually quite correct on this. Your solution is probably best met by overriding the Application to include a static Timer that can be started and stopped by any of your Activities. Its a super-boss way to handle things that need to be shared between components and avoids unnecessary threading and intent passing. Since you have already overridden your own Timer, this should not be a hassle for you.

Comment: I was thinking if we can use fragment to cater for this problem as the fragment will always carry the textview with which i'm trying to attach the timer. I've tried retaining the fragment but always a new one gets invoked with the creation of a new activity. any help on it?

Comment: I think you're fundamentally missing how activities work.  An Activity is a self contained thing.  You need to think of it, sort of, like a web page.  A web page doesn't know anything about any other web page, and if you need 2 web pages to share information you have to do something to make that a reality (cookies, query strings, etc). Activities, at least in this regard, are quite similar. The difference is that you do have a thing called Application, which sits above all the Activities (that come and go) and maintains state. So... just use it!

Answer (score 0):

I think you must think about using a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) :

> Thus a Service itself is actually very simple, providing two main
>   features:
>
> - A facility for the application to tell the system about something it wants to be doing in the background (even when the user is not
>     directly interacting with the application). This corresponds to calls
>     to Context.startService(), which ask the system to schedule work for
>     the service, to be run until the service or someone else explicitly
>     stop it.
> - A facility for an application to expose some of its functionality to other applications. This corresponds to calls to
>     Context.bindService(), which allows a long-standing connection to be
>     made to the service in order to interact with it. When a Service
>     component is actually created, for either of these reasons, all that
>     the system actually does is instantiate the component and call its
>     onCreate() and any other appropriate callbacks on the main thread. It
>     is up to the Service to implement these with the appropriate behavior,
>     such as creating a secondary thread in which it does its work.

Comment: If I understand his needs, a Service is total overkill in this situation, but yes, it's an alternative.